# Use Humanize.intword function in every row and numeric column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, humanize

I have a dataset with very big numbers. I would like to facilitate reading by using the `humanize.intword` function in all columns except the date.

[image]

When I select only one column, it works:

```
pred_df["Predictions"].apply(lambda x: humanize.intword(x))
```

When I try to select other numeric columns, I get an error:

> pred_df.apply(lambda row : humanize.intword(row['Predictions'],row['Lower'], row['Upper']), axis = 1)
>
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

I also tried list comprehensions as suggested in this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas` but I am probably doing something wrong. It works for one single column:

```
[humanize.intword(x) for x in pred_df["Predictions"]]
```

When I try over different columns I get an error:

> [humanize.intword(row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJwnK.png), row[11]) for row in zip(pred_df["Predictions"],pred_df["Lower"])]
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

My dataframe contains 12 rows and 4 columns. Can you help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `humanize.intword` works with a single value and converts it. But aim here is to convert *many* numbers. One way is to [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df.set_index("fiscal_date").applymap(humanize.intword)
```

where we first set the date as the index to not use it in the calculations. You can put it back to a column with a `reset_index()` afterwards if you wish.

---

As to why you get errors or not:

> When I select only one column, it works:

Because you select a series and what are passed to `apply` are single entries of that column; and it works.

> When I try to select other numeric columns, I get an error:

Because you'd be supplying 3 values to `intword` but it can only work with 1 + 1, where first is the value to convert and other is the optional format. (The error message should've been something like "this function takes 1 to 2 arguments but you gave 3", I believe.)

> It works for one single column:

Again, this is akin to first `apply` over one column.

> When I try over different columns I get an error:

Again, `intword` can work with one value at a time. (But the error is because you gave `11` as an index to `row` which has 2 elements only coming from those 2 columns' entries.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the code but also the explanations. It is very clear, I understood it now. I really appreciate it!